# how to display a graphic time line in play framework

Tags: jquery, database, playframework

how do you think is the simple way to make a graphic time line,

like this:

**view by:** 
 years 
 month 
days **X**

### -----------------------------------------

### **name_book**-------**day6**------**day7**-------**day8**

---

### xxx-123---------5h--------2h----------1h

---

### xxx-321---------1h---------4h---------2h

---

may be something like that...
i has think in jquery but i didn't see any that works with database...

any one have done some similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to create a graph? Have you looked at for example google charts? 
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html